# PySide2 erro ao usar o metodo QWidget.render(), como contornar?

Tags: python-3.x, pyside

Estou tendo problemas para imprimir um widget. Ao executar o código abaixo é retornado um erro.

```
    #p é uma instancia QPrinter

    painter = QPainter(p)
    painter.setRenderHint(QPainter.HighQualityAntialiasing)
    xscale = p.pageRect().width()/ self.width()
    yscale = p.pageRect().height()/ self.height()
    scale = min(xscale, yscale)
    painter.translate(p.paperRect().center())
    painter.scale(scale, scale)
    painter.translate((self.width()/2)*-1,(self.height()/2)*-1)
    self.render(painter)
    painter.end()
```

O error retornado é:

> TypeError: 'PySide2.QtWidgets.QWidget.render' called with wrong argument types:
> PySide2.QtWidgets.QWidget.render(QPainter)
> PySide2.QtWidgets.QWidget.render(PySide2.QtGui.QPaintDevice, PySide2.QtCore.QPoint = Default(QPoint), PySide2.QtGui.QRegion = Default(QRegion), PySide2.QtWidgets.QWidget.RenderFlags = Instance(QWidget.RenderFlags(QWidget.DrawWindowBackground | QWidget.DrawChildren)))

O que não estou entendendo é, esse mesmo código no PyQt5 funciona sem problemas. Alguém poderia ajudar ?

obs: não gostaria de usar o pyqt5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tente passar os parametros do metodo *render* explicitamente, tente o seguinte:

```
    painter = QPainter(p)
    painter.setRenderHint(QPainter.HighQualityAntialiasing)
    xscale = p.pageRect().width()/ self.width()
    yscale = p.pageRect().height()/ self.height()
    scale = min(xscale, yscale)
    painter.translate(p.paperRect().center())
    painter.scale(scale, scale)
    painter.translate((self.width()/2)*-1,(self.height()/2)*-1)
    self.render(painter,QPoint(0,0),painter.viewport()) #parametros expliclitos
    painter.end()
```